# Race condition when using tf.assign in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, graph, race-condition

How do you deal with the race condition when using tf.assign()?
For example, if my code is the following:

```
y = tf.Variable(6,trainable=False,name='y');
x = tf.Variable(0,trainable=False,name='x');
assign_op = tf.assign( x, 2 );
divide_op = y/assign_op;
answer = sess.run([divide_op]);
```

My answer is either 3 or 0inf.. The only thing that I can think of is splitting up the sess.run into this:

```
_ = sess.run([assign_op]);
answer = sess.run([divide_op]);
```

I thought that creating a operation dependency like I did above would solve the issue of there being a race condition but it doesn't. Does anyone know what to do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into control_dependencies flow control functions:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#control_dependencies

```
with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
    divide_op = y/assign_op
```

This will make sure the "assign_op" has completed prior to the graph elements in the block.

Comment: So, if I am chaining the references from assign operations, I would need multiple control_dependencies to ensure that the previous assignment has completed before proceeding? What if I am using the reference assign_op in two locations? Can both equations go inside the control_dependencies?

I'll try it and post back.Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, if they are all independent you should be able to add then in the list [], so [assign_op, assign_op2, assign_op3].  You may need to change a few control_dependencies if there is still ambiguity in operating order.

Comment: Just as an additional note, the split sess.run() will only work if you are assigning values to a variable as the graph is ultimately reset after each .run().  To get around that, there was a partial_run() what was proposed about a year ago, not sure that made it into the python API or not.

Comment: I just read the documentation and it made sense for my problem. Thank you!